# How to write integration test for typed client in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, polly

I have a .NET 7 console application that fetches data from an API.

The console application is simple and uses a "typed client", that I am writing:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyTypedClient, MyTypedClient>();
services.AddHttpClient<IMyTypedClient, MyTypedClient>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.randomnumberapi.com/api/v1.0/");
    })
    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());

static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(6, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
}
```

Here is the "typed client":

```
public class MyTypedClient : IMyTypedClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyTypedClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public void GetRandomNumber()
    {
        var response = _httpClient.GetAsync("/random?min=1&max=10&count=5").Result;
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to get random number");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is inspired by [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

**Question**
I would like to integration test the **"typed client" part of the app** that I am writing while developing it, but how do I create integration tests for this typed client that takes a `HttpClient`?

Comment: Please add how the app is receiving input and how it is providing output.

Comment: @Emond The app is running continuously, ie. it will attempt to fetch a random number every 2 minutes. What I want is just to have integration tests of the "typed client" component of the app.

Comment: What does it do with the retrieved results?

Comment: @Emond Printing the result is ok, later I want to make a request to another API and "import" the result, but I just want to make the typed client first.

Comment: 1. Go async all the way. Don't use `.Result`. You are asking for trouble. 2. What is your integration test supposed to test? What precisely?

Comment: @Fildor 1. True. 2. The integration test is just supposed to test I get a HTTP 200 and print the result from the API, that's all.

Comment: If the console app does not take input and it does not output anything, a meaningful integration test cannot be done.

Comment: @Emond Thank you for your answer. I am interested in testing the "typed client" component of the app. Why is that not meaningful to do before the app "outputs" something?

Comment: I am trying to understand why you want an integration test and not a unit test, Do you want to test the resiliency policies that you have configured ?

Comment: @YK1 Sorry for not being clear, it was just meant as a tool during development. I would mark it explicit, since it is unpredictable if the external service works. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing the following helper method in my "test" fixture:

```
    const string baseUrl = "https://someurl";
    const string accessToken = "token";

    var httpClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
    };


    return new MyTypedClient(httpClient, accessToken);
```